# Closing a modal only if the confirmation is accepted in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to make a modal with a close and add button. When I click close, a small dialog shows to ask if you really want to quit the modal, but when I click ok, it does not close the modal. Does anyone know why this is?

My modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick ="return confirm('Do you really want to quit?');" data-backdrop="static">Close</button>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return confirm('Do you really want to quit?');` doesn't do anything. You should use jQuery to hide the modal.

If you really want to use `confirm`, you could use the following in-line command or use a separate function.

Suppose the id of the modal is "test_modal", then:

```
<div class="modal-footer" id="test_modal">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
            onclick ="confirm('Do you really want to quit?')? $('#test_modal').modal('hide') : false" 
            data-backdrop="static">Close</button>
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this works but only removes the actual footer, not the whole modal... any idea why?

Comment: You should use the id of the whole modal to replace `test_modal` here. `test_modal` is an example here just for demonstration. It's the id of footer, so only footer is removed.

Comment: Ah yes!! thank you! it is still problematic though. The background remains dim, as when the modal is open and you can interact with the screen.

Comment: I have update the answer.

Comment: nice!! what change did you make?

Comment: Use `$('#test_modal').modal('hide')` instead of `$('#test_modal').hide()`.